2 Canvas Power Apps with separate Offline profiles
I am running 2 canvas power-apps that live in 2 separate solutions within the same environment that have dataverse tables set for offline use, when adding a user to an offline profile, for app1, that has already been assigned to the offline for app2.  I am prompted with an exception message stating "This user belongs to an existing profile: app2Profile".  When I created an offline profile with all tables moved for both apps, and then assigned that offline profile to both apps, an error message was displayed on my mobile device stating "Sharing the same offline profile between canvas apps is not supported for now.  Please create a new offline profile for this app and then republish it".
Does anyone know what needs to be configured/setup so that 2 canvas apps set up for offline dataverse table functionality can be used in parallel by the same user in the same environment, with both apps living in their own separate solutions?Screenshot of error message on mobile device
Tried creating 1 offline profile for both apps, error message returned is in screen shot.  Tried creating 2 canvas apps in same solution, same error message displayed when downloading app to device.
